# How do I filter the rows using the datediff function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following structure:

```
+===========+============+
| titleName |    date    |
+===========+============+
|  title1   | 2016-08-06 |
+===========+============+
|  title2   | 2016-08-03 |
+===========+============+
|  title3   | 2016-07-29 |
+===========+============+
|  title4   | 2016-08-09 |
+===========+============+
|  title5   | 2016-09-03 |
+===========+============+
```

I want to select only the rows that are not older than 90 days from the current date (2016-11-04) as follows:

```
+===========+============+
| titleName |    date    |
+===========+============+
|  title4   | 2016-08-09 |
+===========+============+
|  title5   | 2016-09-03 |
+===========+============+
```

I have tried the following query, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
SELECT titleName, Datediff(NOW(), publish_date) AS datediff FROM myTable ORDER BY titleName DESC LIMIT 8
```

Please help me to make the correct query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WHERE` clause with an `INTERVAL`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE `date` + INTERVAL 90 DAY >= NOW();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where publish_date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 90 day);
```

If you want to see the number of days, then include the `datediff()` expression in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine

`SELECT titleName, date FROM mytable WHERE Datediff(NOW(), date)<90 ORDER BY titleName DESC LIMIT 8`